# Google Blocked Resources - Images - Cannot figure out where it's coming from

Tags: google-search-console, images, render

I just discovered the google blocked resources, and it shows that for about 45 items, when I click on the fetch and render, that it's partial, and it shows that a resource is blocked and it shows that it's images, and the resource is showing as:

http://1434513228829.7p3mxx16x2qhbybull8002elikymn2.volluto.com/img/image-l.gif?t=1434513228829&c=7p3mxx16x2qhbybull8002elikymn2&p=eyceny

I'm on Shopify and they have no clue what it is, they say it's not coming from them but from possibly a 3rd party application but no clue which one as they can't find any reference to any part of this url in the code - I have every which way searched parts of the url to see what it could be but nothing comes up, and this 'volluto.com' that's in the url is a parked page and no info on it. So i'm just beyond frustrated, does any one here have a clue what this resource is that's blocking images, it just started apparently a few weeks ago per the info in webmaster tools - what is odd though is when I fetch and render the googlebot version of my webpage and my version of the webpage are exactly the same, there is nothing missing from the webpage visually .... so could there be a mistake in fetch and render or blocked resources or did someone put something on my site that even shopify can't find? Please help I dont' know where else to look ...

Answer (score 1):

I checked:

`http://1434513228829.7p3mxx16x2qhbybull8002elikymn2.volluto.com/robots.txt`

And it turns out that every URL attached to this domain is meant to be inaccessible by search engines and other respectful robots with the exception of robots.txt. Since Google completely respects rules in robots.txt, they will complain about blocked resources for all URLs beginning with `http://1434513228829.7p3mxx16x2qhbybull8002elikymn2.volluto.com`.

To fix this, Ask whoever has document root access to the site to modify their robots.txt file so that google has access to it.

Comment: Thanks Mike - but Shopify is saying that this URL or everything attached to volluto.com domain is not coming from Shopify but rather a 3rd party resource like an app so i'm taking it to mean they don't have access - and they have no clue what app it is and honestly I don't completely either, and Shopify will not change their robots.txt file for anyone they have it set specifically and they power 70000 stores a lot that are big names and so it seems random it happened to me so if I could figure out what this volluto.com is, all I know it has it's own dedicated IP on Amazon and it uses their AWS

Comment: Another option would be to store the images elsewhere where they are not blocked by robots.txt and modify your HTML code so that the new image locations are referenced.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same issue and it has to do with riskified.com.  They have a javascript file that calls http://beacon.riskified.com/?shop=whatever.com&ts=12345 and that references volluto.com.  Based on this, I don't think it should be a great concern.